# Transferring listbox options values to the server

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

I have a form, which contains 2 List-boxes among other input fields.
I'm moving content (options in the Listbox) from one Listbox to another(left-right or vice-versa) on click of a button. Like [this example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/listbox-select-all-move-left-right-up-down-javascript/). Now I need the content of both the Listboxes on the server.On form submit, I can only transfer the selected values in the listbox to the server, not all the options. So I have 2 options:

1. On click event of the button which transfers content from left to right, I make an Ajax call sending the content to the server.
2. Before submitting the form, I put all the values of the listbox in a hidden field so on form submit, I can access it on the server

Which of these is better for my situation??
EDIT: Drawback of implementing the first method is that every time the user transfers content from Listbox A to B, a trip to the server will be made via Ajax

Answer (score 0):

You may also query the `listbox` source again to get the other values that are not select in post method

Comment: Say u have A,B,C,D in List Box and A,C are transferred. In you post Method call the GetOtherVAlue(send select value) and in query filter values that are other than A.C. It will return B,D

Answer (score 0):

I would send all the content of the listbox (if it's feasible for you) with the first pageload and use jquery to move items between lists (so no more ajax calls)

And send the items back to the server like in this example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.TextBox("movies")
@Html.TextBox("movies")
@Html.TextBox("movies")
<input type=submit />
}
```

We have used the Html.TextBox helper to create three input elements; these will all be created with a
value of movies for the name attribute, like this:

```
<input id="movies" name="movies" type="text" value="" />
<input id="movies" name="movies" type="text" value="" />
<input id="movies" name="movies" type="text" value="" />
```

We can receive the values that the user enters with an action method like the one shown in
Listing 17-11.
Listing 17-11. Receiving Multiple Data Items in an Action Method

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Movies(List<string> movies) {
...
```

The model binder will find all the values supplied by the user and pass them to the Movies action
method in a List. The binder is smart enough to support different parameter types; we can
choose to receive the data as a string[] or even as an IList.

From Apress Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Book

Comment: But after moving items between listboxes, how would you send the new content of the listboxes?

Comment: You can have a parameter of type List<string> in your controller method and catch all the values of the listbox in that method

Comment: But how would you send them to the server in the first place?

Comment: But I've used : @Html.ListBox("name",(SelectList)ViewBag.something)

Comment: then have a List<string> name parameter in your serverside method. The binder will bind all the values inside that listbox to your List<string>